# gulp-ruby-sass TypeError when using .pipe(sass({style:'expanded'))

Tags: gulp

OK. I am having trouble with this code. I've used gulp-ruby-sass before, but I have not encountered this kind of error until now. I am using gulp-ruby-sass 1.0.0. I am simply trying to use gulp-ruby-sass to run my sass files in css. However, this is obviously not working. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here's the error:

```
 TypeError: string is not a function
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxx/gulpfile.js:22:15)
    at module.exports (/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxx/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxx/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxx/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxx/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
```

The Gulp code I am using for my project is the following:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = ('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint');

var paths = {
    sass: 'stylesheets/scss/',
    css: 'stylesheets/css'
    };

gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src('angular/app.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter());
    });

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.sass + '*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass({style: 'expanded'})) // HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css + '*.css'))
        .pipe(livereload());
    });

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('angular/app.js')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('angular/minjs'))
        .pipe(livereload());
    });

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch(paths.sass + '*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('angular/app.js', ['scripts']);
    });

gulp.task('default', ['lint', 'sass', 'scripts', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Aperçu for spotting the error of not putting `require` at the beginning of `('gulp-ruby-sass)`. Stupid mistake.

So here is the answer that is working which I got from the new documentation for [Gulp-Ruby-Sass 1.0.0-alpha](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/tree/rw/1.0). The new documentation notes that you have to get rid of `gulp src`. Here's the code I used to make everything work.

**Old Code**

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.sass + '*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass({style: 'expanded'})) // HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css + '*.css'))
        .pipe(livereload());
    });
```

**New Code**

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return sass(paths.sass, {style: 'expanded'}) 
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css))
        .pipe(livereload());
});
```

Note: the new documentation does not support globs.